# Module '"react-hook-form"' has no exported member 'useForm'

Tags: react-hook-form

This is my code below. Typescript give me error, i try to install @types/react but still same. Please refer my code below.

```
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";

const formSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Server name is required.",
  }),
});

export const InitialModal = () => {
  const form = useForm({
    defaultValus: {
      name: "",
      imageUrl: "",
    },
  });

  return (
    <Dialog open>
      <DialogContent className="bg-white text-black p-0 overflow-hidden">
        <DialogHeader className="pt-8 px-6">
          <DialogTitle className="text-2xl text-center font-bold">
            Customize your server
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription className="text-center text-zinc-500">
            Give your server a personality with a name and image. You can always
            change it later.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

I also try to change typescript version from package.json. But still fail. Please assits

Comment: was this resolved? facing exact same issue